# Passing a rendered dynamic aspx page to Report Writer 3.0

Tags: reporting-services

What I am looking for is a way to render a dynamic aspx page to some type of format that I can pass to  MS SQL 2008 R2 server based report writer to be outputted as the first page of the report.

I have many reports to write. Most if not all, have a aspx launch page that contains a collection of dropdowns and radiobuttons for filtering the dataset that will be rendered by the report writer. As the user selects the criteria the displayed page via callbacks changes its appearance to reflect the choices the user has made until they finally press the GENERATE button to launch the report passing report parameters in. That final version of the page with its user selections show is the one that I wish to pass to the report writer.

Report Builder 3 appears allows multiple datasets and multiple tables to be displayed on the report canvas.

Having a rendered copy of the selection aspx page will simplify having to display it without have to write a separate stored procedure for each and every report to layout its unique selection parameters at the start of the report.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to send the raw aspx page to SSRS for rendering.  My approach to this issue would be to create a sub-report that looks a lot like the aspx page, and pass the report parameters to this report to generate the SSRS "look-alike".  Not sure if this approach would work in your case or not, depending on how dynamic your aspx page is when users select various parameters.

Another option (much more complicated) would be to render the aspx page as an image (there are several 3rd party tools out there to help accomplish this task if you Google it).  Store the image in a database or file share--somewhere accessible by SSRS, and then pass the appropriate reference to SSRS.  SSRS can display the image.

Comment: Is there a way to render to say a text file that I could pass as an extra parameter to the report writer. But good idea with the image generator. I will evaluate that. Thanks